# What is the puppet warp equivalent in Pencil2D or Sketch or Gimp?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

- [Photoshop Tutorial: Puppet Warp!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIYxyQ2s64c)

I want to do puppet warp in Pencil2D or Sketch or Gimp.

Does these three software have this facility?

Comment: I don't use Pencil2D or Sketch, but GIMP has nothing that is an equivalent.  Although there's nothing to stop you from manually cutting out pieces of an image, and then rotating them.

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, user366312! I'm not aware of such a tool for GIMP, perhaps you can try to combine the [Cage Tool](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-tool-cage.html) and the [Warp Transform Tool](https://docs.gimp.org/2.10/en/gimp-tool-warp.html), see [this example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLt3Uo5cMbA) or enable the [n-point deformation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieaHvHAcNRE) (experimental, see [here](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-The-Playground)).